# WSO2 APIM API invocation error

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have set up `WSO2 API Manager` and set up an API. Tried to invoke it via `APIM console` itself .But it says NO response from client.

I enabled `log4j.logger.org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire=DEBUG` and found out the below error in the `wso2-apigw-errors.log`.

```
2016-12-28 17:10:08,725 [-] [DataBridge-ConnectionService-tcp://192.168.1.33:9620-pool-7-thread-1] ERROR DataEndpointConnectionWorker Error while opening socket to 192.168.1.33:9720. Connection refused: connect
org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointException: Error while opening socket to 192.168.1.33:9720. Connection refused: connect
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.binary.BinarySecureClientPoolFactory.createClient(BinarySecureClientPoolFactory.java:58)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.client.AbstractClientPoolFactory.makeObject(AbstractClientPoolFactory.java:39)
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1212)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:92)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.run(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:43)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:656)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.<init>(SSLSocketImpl.java:415)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(SSLSocketFactoryImpl.java:88)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.binary.BinarySecureClientPoolFactory.createClient(BinarySecureClientPoolFactory.java:53)
    ... 9 more
2016-12-28 17:10:08,725 [-] [DataBridge-ConnectionService-tcp://192.168.1.33:9620-pool-7-thread-1] ERROR DataEndpointConnectionWorker Error while trying to connect to the endpoint. Cannot borrow client for ssl://192.168.1.33:9720
org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointAuthenticationException: Cannot borrow client for ssl://192.168.1.33:9720
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:100)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.run(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:43)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointException: Error while opening socket to 192.168.1.33:9720. Connection refused: connect
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.binary.BinarySecureClientPoolFactory.createClient(BinarySecureClientPoolFactory.java:58)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.client.AbstractClientPoolFactory.makeObject(AbstractClientPoolFactory.java:39)
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1212)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:92)
    ... 6 more
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: attach logs is something related to data publisher. if you enable wire log request and response will get printed as in blog http://mytecheye.blogspot.com/2013/09/wso2-esb-all-about-wire-logs.html

Comment: Can you please what is the log file name?

Comment: the main error message i see is 
TID: [-1] [] [2016-12-28 22:14:14,246] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker} -  Error while trying to connect to the endpoint. Cannot borrow client for ssl://192.168.1.36:9711 {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker}
org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointAuthenticationException: Cannot borrow client for ssl://192.168.1.36:9711

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the last comment, I believe your issue will be fixed by the answer given in [Error while trying to connect to the endpoint. Cannot borrow client for ssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41367492/error-while-trying-to-connect-to-the-endpoint-cannot-borrow-client-for-ssl)

Comment: I have no error now..But i get response body as empty... 
Ideally the service should return a json..
Response Body
no content

Comment: If the curl works but API console doesn't it can be a cert issue. Copy URL to browser and accept the cert. Then try again in API console.

Comment: curl itself is not working..The response  code is 200 but response body is No Content and  response headers is {
  "content-type": null
}

Comment: if response code is 200, it's working. problem must be with the backend. post wire logs.

Comment: http://lakshanigamage.blogspot.com/2015/03/how-to-enable-wire-logs-in-wso2-esbapim.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131831/discussion-between-jocket-and-bhathiya).

Comment: I tried to hit a public avaialbe API bbc.co.uk/radio1/… its the same...
I enabled the logs ..but which log to check?