# Cannot borrow client for ssl://10.10.183.27:9714. org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-esb

I'm trying to connect my wso2 API manager to external LDAP/Active Directory. LDAP connection is fine but I'm getting this error while starting the server.

`9714` is SSL port

`[2018-07-13 14:52:03,250] ERROR - JMSListener Unable to continue server startup as it seems the JMS Provider is not yet started. Please start the JMS provider now.
[2018-07-13 14:52:03,251] ERROR - JMSListener Connection attempt : 5 for JMS Provider failed. Next retry in 320 seconds
[2018-07-13 14:52:27,889]  WARN - DataEndpointGroup No receiver is reachable at reconnection, will try to reconnect every 30 sec
[2018-07-13 14:52:27,906]  INFO - DataBridge user admin connected
[2018-07-13 14:52:27,914] ERROR - AuthenticationServiceImpl Invalid User : admin
[2018-07-13 14:52:27,915] ERROR - DataEndpointConnectionWorker Error while trying to connect to the endpoint. Cannot borrow client for ssl://10.10.183.27:9714.
org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointLoginException: Cannot borrow client for ssl://10.10.183.27:9714.
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:134)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.run(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:59)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointLoginException: 
 Error while trying to login to data receiver :/10.10.183.27:9714
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.binary.BinaryDataEndpoint.login(BinaryDataEndpoint.java:50) at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:128)
        ... 6 more`

Comment: [Question Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41367492/error-while-trying-to-connect-to-the-endpoint-cannot-borrow-client-for-ssl) seems to be the same but I don't understand, How did it get resolved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error usually is due to the Analytics configuration or Throttling configuration.

Try to disable the Analytics publisher in the api-manager.xml file, if enabled, or review the connection details under DASServerUrl element.

```xml
<Analytics>
    <!-- Enable Analytics for API Manager -->
    <Enabled>false</Enabled>

    <!-- Server URL of the remote DAS/CEP server used to collect statistics. Must
         be specified in protocol://hostname:port/ format.

         An event can also be published to multiple Receiver Groups each having 1 or more receivers. Receiver
         Groups are delimited by curly braces whereas receivers are delimited by commas.
         Ex - Multiple Receivers within a single group
         tcp://localhost:7612/,tcp://localhost:7613/,tcp://localhost:7614/

         Ex - Multiple Receiver Groups with two receivers each
         {tcp://localhost:7612/,tcp://localhost:7613},{tcp://localhost:7712/,tcp://localhost:7713/} -->
    <DASServerURL>{tcp://localhost:7612}</DASServerURL>
    <!--DASAuthServerURL>{ssl://localhost:7712}</DASAuthServerURL-->
    <!-- Administrator username to login to the remote DAS server. -->
    <DASUsername>${admin.username}</DASUsername>
    <!-- Administrator password to login to the remote DAS server. -->
    <DASPassword>${admin.password}</DASPassword>
```

You can also try to disable, or review the configuration in ReceiverUrlGroup and AuthUrlGroup, of the Advanced Throttling feature.

```xml
<ThrottlingConfigurations>
    <EnableAdvanceThrottling>false</EnableAdvanceThrottling>
    <DataPublisher>
        <Enabled>true</Enabled>
        <Type>Binary</Type>
        <ReceiverUrlGroup>tcp://${carbon.local.ip}:${receiver.url.port}</ReceiverUrlGroup>
        <AuthUrlGroup>ssl://${carbon.local.ip}:${auth.url.port}</AuthUrlGroup>
        <Username>${admin.username}</Username>
        <Password>${admin.password}</Password>
```

Comment: Analytics is already disabled, `<DASServerURL>` is also set to localhost:7612. `<AuthURLGrpup>` is also same. But my localhost IP is not `127.0.0.1.` Can it affect it in any way?

Comment: If Analytics is disabled the error could be related to Throttling. The `EnableAdvanceThrottling` in `ThrottlingConfigurations` section, is it enabled? If so, how did you configure the 'AuthUrlGroup` and `ReceiverUrlGroup` values? Is the port 9714 listening to the right network interface?

Comment: Yes, You're right. I made `EnableAdvanceThrottling` false and I'm not getting the error. But i think I won't be able to do anything with throttling policy.
Is there any workaround to avoid the error without disabling the `EnableAdvanceThrottling`? Do you know the exact root cause for the error? Why throttling is throwing `org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception (SSL)` error?

Comment: If you have an all-in-one installation you could try to manual set the connection  url to the internal traffic manager. If you have an offset of 3, try: `<ReceiverUrlGroup>tcp://localhost:9614</ReceiverUrlGroup>` and `<AuthUrlGroup>ssl://localhost:9714</AuthUrlGroup>`.

Comment: Totally Worked, You rock!

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. Check the log of traffic manager, if there arn't any exceptions. Kill & start traffic manager helped me.