# Unable to make change in api-manager.xml in wso2-am 3.0

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I am using `wso2` api manager 3.0 and unable to make any changes in api-manager.xml, whatever changes, I made those get reverted after the restart of server. I tried it from changing the `off-set` port and dev portal `url`.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 4):

In API Manager 3.0.0, the configuration model has been changed. All configurations can be found in a single file named as deployment.toml which is located in <APIM-Home>/repository/conf.

You have to add/change configurations in that file. For instance, in order to change the offset, uncomment **offset** and provide the offset.

You can refer [1] for sample configurations. As you mentioned, changed applied to api-manager.xml will be overridden with the values configured in deployment.toml

Please note that documentations are in-progress. It will be updated with missing configs information

**Update**

[1] https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.0.0/reference/config-catalog/

Comment: @VishnuChandel Updated the link

Comment: If you are looking for 3.1.0 docs, the link is - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/config-catalog/

Comment: Thank you. It works. Just do not forget to enable all the section if you will change the URL.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @Vithursa M, is necessary to update deployment.toml which is located in /repository/conf.

But do not forget, that if you will enable the one line, you have to enable whole section, otherwise i.e. traffic_manager_urls will be then updated as empty in api-manager.xml

Here is my working solution.

```
[[apim.throttling.url_group]]
#traffic_manager_urls = ["tcp://localhost:9611","tcp://localhost:9611"]
traffic_manager_urls = ["tcp://localhost:9611"]
#traffic_manager_auth_urls = ["ssl://localhost:9711","ssl://localhost:9711"]
traffic_manager_auth_urls = ["ssl://localhost:9711"]
#type = "loadbalance"
```